# How can I redirect with old input in Laravel?

Tags: php, forms, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I have a login modal. When the user log-in fail the authentication, I want to redirect back to this modal with :

- error message(s)
- and old input(s).

[image]

---

## Controller

```
// if Auth Fail 
return Redirect::to('/')
                ->with('error','Username/Password Wrong')
                ->withInput(Request::except('password'))
                ->withErrors($validator);
```

---

## Form

```
{!! Form::open(array('url' => '/', 'class' => 'login-form')) !!}

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="username">Username</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control"  id="username" name="username" placeholder="Enter Username" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter Password" required>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

---

As you can see as part of my image, the error message seem to display, but the old input of username doesn't seem to populate.

Can someone please correct me ?
Did I forget to do anything ?
What is the most efficient way in Laravel to accomplish something like this ?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can access the last inputs like so:

`$username = Request::old('username');`

As pointed at by [@Arian Acosta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2188595/arian-acosta) you may simply do

`<input type="text" ... value="{{ old('username') }}" ... >`.

As described in the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/requests#old-input) it is more convenient in a blade view.

---

There are several possibilties in the controller:

Instead of
  `->withInput(Request::except('password'))`

do:

*a)* `Input::flash();`

or:

*b)* `Input::flashExcept('password');`

and redirect to the view with:

*a)* `->withInput(Input::except('password'));`

resp. with:

*b)* `->withInput();`

The [docs about Old Input](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/requests#old-input) for further reading...

Comment: Your solution is working for me. I got my old input to display now. Thank you so much.

Comment: Please take off `Request::flash();` I don't need to do that.

Comment: Glad I could help. Yepp, because `Request::except('password')` already does it.

Comment: old() is also a global, you don't need to use Request::old('username'). Simply do value="{{ old('username') }}"

Comment: Input::flash() is cool when you use the "what was the name of the redirect to GET route after request to POST route - HTTP pattern again?" Ah PRG pattern

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
 return redirect()->back()
       ->with('error','username is invalid')
       ->withInput();
```

make sure you have `value="{{ old('username') }}"` in your input element

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the value on your input element...

```
value="{{ Input::get ('username', '') }}"
```

Comment: This doesn't work ! I've tried  `<input type="text" class="form-control"  id="username" name="username" placeholder="Enter Username" required value="{{ Input::get ('username', '') }}" >` and nothing seem to populate.

Answer (score 0):

**For my project, I needed another way:**

Shove a `GET` request in the validation return to fetch some previous data:

```
   // if the validator fails, redirect back to the form
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        //let's send some data back (Orlando,Florida):
        return Redirect::to('auth/register?city=Orlando&State=Florida')
            ->withErrors($validator)


    }else{
     //validation success
    }
```