# Laravel 7 - How to display old input in login form after redirected back due to failed login attempt?

Tags: php, laravel, redirect

I am trying to display the old inputted data by a user before the user's failed attempt to login in the login form but it does not display the old data in email input field though I successfully retrieved in in my controller (Checked it using `dd()`).

Tried all the solutions here but none works for me: [How can I redirect with old input in Laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30002608/how-can-i-redirect-with-old-input-in-laravel)

> How to **display the previous/old input** (E-Mail address only) in the
> login form e-mail input field?

Here's my LoginController's `login` method snippet code:

```
public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required',
        ]);
        $request->flash();

        $inputs = $request;

        $remember = $request->has('remember') ? true : false;
        
        if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $request->input('email'), 'password' => $request->input('password')], $remember))
        {
            activity()
            ->useLog("User")
            ->causedBy(Auth::user())
            ->performedOn(Auth::user())
            ->log('Logged-In.');
            
            return redirect('/home');
        }else{
            Toastr::error('The E-Mail Address and/or Password you inputted is wrong.', 'Error');
            //dd($request->except('password'));
            return redirect('/login')->withInput($request->except('password'));
        }
    }
```

Here's my snippet code for my `login.blade.php`:

```
<div class="input-group mb-3">
     <input id="email" 
            type="email" 
            class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" 
            name="email" 
            value="{{ old('email') }}" 
            placeholder = "E-Mail Address" 
            required>

            @error('email')
                 <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                     <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                 </span>
            @enderror
            <div class="input-group-append">
                <div class="input-group-text">
                     <span class="fas fa-envelope"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
 </div>
```

Here's my login form:

[image]

Comment: This old method only work if it fails `$this->validate` method. Otherwise you need to send it with from controller. `->with("old_email", $request-email);` & In blade  `{{ $old_email ??  old('email') ??  null }}`

Comment: I tried {{ $old_email ??  old('email') ??  null }} this method and still the same. Btw thanks for clarification about $this->validate :)

Comment: @STA The old method does not only work if validation fails. "To retrieve flashed input from the previous request, use the old method" And "Since you often will want to flash input to the session and then redirect to the previous page, you may easily chain input flashing onto a redirect using the withInput method" https://laravel.com/docs/master/requests#old-input